# ShortDatePattern is not returning server DateFormat

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a scenario where I want to get the **ShortDatePattern** of server machine. I need to find out the Short Date Format. If it is not in "mm/dd/yyyy" I need to show the message at client code written in c#.

For ex if I set the server date format as "dd/mm/yyyy". At client code, which is in c# I always get the value as 'M/dd/yyyy'.

I tried below ways to get the ShortDatePattern but both of them are returning 'm/dd/yyyy' only.

1. System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
2. System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern

This is the code that I'm using

```
// DateFormat should be in Month/Date/Year format. Regex to match with first client  
// and thn server ShortDatePattern.   
string matchDatePattern = "^M{1,3}/d{1,2}/y{1,4}$"; 

// This is how I get the ShortDatePattern of Client.  
string clientDateFormat = **System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern**; 

if (!Regex.IsMatch(clientDateFormat, matchDatePattern))
{
   ModuleMessageDisplay.DisplayMessageBox("The Short Date Format of your system is not  supported by Application.", DPResources.MyResources.MessageBoxTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
   return;
}


// It returns the value fetched from Server. **Used the same code as mentioned above to get client format(Highlighted in Bold). I set the server ShortDatePattern as ‘dd-mm-yyyy’**.
```

I was expecting it would return the value from ShortDatePattern as ‘dd-mm-yyyy’ at client but the it returned format as ‘M/dd/yyyy’ which is neither set at client nor at server side.

```
string serverDateFormat = DPCommonControls.ModuleCaches.GetBuildNumberAndDateFormat().Split('|')[1];  
if (!Regex.IsMatch(serverDateFormat, matchDatePattern))
{
   ModuleMessageDisplay.DisplayMessageBox("The Short Date Format of the server is not supported by Application.", DPResources.MyResources.MessageBoxTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
   return;
 }
```

Any help or pointer would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Please show us the code you have problems with.

Answer (score 1):

use tostring and the format that you want

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("M/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a scenario where I want to get the ShortDatePattern of server
>   machine. I need to find out the Short Date Format.

Sure, you can use [`ShortDatePattern` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as you did. This gets you short pattern of the current culture in server machine.

> If it is not in "mm/dd/yyyy" I need to show the message at client code
>   written in c#

You can compare your property with your pattern like;

```
if(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern != "mm//dd//yyyy")
{
   //Show your messsage
}
```

> For ex if I set the server date format as "dd/mm/yyyy". At client
>   code, which is in c# I always get the value as 'M/dd/yyyy'

From this sentence, I understand you have two seperate code. One is on server, one is on client. Looks like they have different current thread cultures and that's why their short date patterns are different.

> I tried below ways to get the ShortDatePattern but both of them are
>   returning 'm/dd/yyyy' only.
>
> 1. System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
> 2. System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern

As I said, they have different current culture thread. That's why their standart date patterns are different to each other. By the way, [`Thread.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns [`Globalization.CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That's why your both code are equal.

Comment: You are right there are two separate code. One is on server, one is on client. But the problem I'm having is I have set the server ShortDatePattern to "dd-mm-yyyy' format. Now by using this code
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
But when I accessed the server method at client side, it didn't give the value as 'dd-mm-yyyy' which I was expecting. It gave the ShortDatePattern value as 'M/dd/yyyy' which is not which I set on server.